# Results of lava plus water in Terraria?

Tags: terraria

What would happen if I were to channel a large pond of water into a lake of lava?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That, my friend, is how you create [obsidian](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Obsidian).

You can find a very useful guide on farming obsidian [here](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Earthwelling).